# Scaling a Vector to Zero?

Tags: java, math, vector, scale, velocity

In a program i have moving objects. Their velocyties are described with a Vector(x, y).
So, i want the Objects to slow down - if they get speed for example because of a collision i scale them down in the next frames (with the factor 0.999) until they stop, because the velocity is so small, you cannot see them moving (java gets to 1e-50 or sth like that).

Its working, but actually its not correct because scaling them down they will never stop in theory. So how can i let the velocity go to zero, and let it **REACH** zero?

Comment: I the frame rate consistent? If not, consider using a timestamp to set the pace of the deceleration.

Comment: thats not the point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it to zero once it drops below some threshold:

```
if (velocity.magnitude() < threshold) {
    velocity = new Vector(0, 0);
}
```

This *will*, however, eventually happen on its own due to arithmetic underflow.

Comment: yeah, but it wouldnt be right in theory.
magnitude is the same as length, or? 
thank you!

Comment: @T_01 The magnitude is `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`.

Comment: yeah, length is the magnitude in lwjgl. Source: grepcode.